# Google Sign-In With PHP

Tags: php

I'm adding Google Sign-In to my site. I've followed the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) with no problems, it's only when I [authenticate with a backend server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) that I get an error (500 Internal Server Error).

I'm using the [Download the Release instructions](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) and downloading [google-api-php-client-2.2.3.zip](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases). I'm not sure if it's relevant but the PHP version installed on the server is PHP Version 5.2.17

Once unzipped, the contents of the file (src,vendor,composer.json,etc) are then all moved to the root folder of my project and uploaded to the server.

HTML is directly copied and pasted from the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) in order to minimise human error on my end

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    // console.log(id_token);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'googleauth.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);

    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    sessionStorage.refName = profile.getId();
    // console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    // console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    // console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    // console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
}

function signOut() {
    sessionStorage.clear();
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        console.log('User signed out.');
    });
}
```

```
<?php
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $id_token = $_POST["idtoken"];
    echo 'test2';
?>
```

When I comment out the code in the 'vendor/autoload.php' file and instead only have it return "test1", the require_once successfully performs its function and "Signed in as: test1 test2" is successfully logged to the console. 
However when I run the script as originally written by Google I get a 500 (Internal Server Error) and "Signed in as: " is logged to the console.

There are so many files in this api, I'm finding it impossible to navigate. And I'm also finding it hard to believe that Google would release something as important as this in a way that doesn't work straight out of the box.

From my perspective I think that I'm following the instructions verbatim, but does anyone have any suggestions of what they think I might be misinterpreting, or alternatively what I could try differently?

---------------edited to add error log from server (with personal details replaced with $ signs)-----------------------

```
$$$$$/error_log:
[25-Jul-2019 23:35:39] PHP Warning:  require_once(__DIR__/composer/autoload_real.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /$$$$$$$/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
[25-Jul-2019 23:35:39] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear') in /$$$$$$$/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
[26-Jul-2019 01:17:47] PHP Warning:  require_once(__DIR__/composer/autoload_real.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /$$$$$$/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
[26-Jul-2019 01:17:47] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear') in /$$$$$/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
[26-Jul-2019 20:05:09] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This library must be installed via composer or by downloading the full package. See the instructions at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation.' in /$$$$$/src/Google/autoload.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /$$$$$/googleauth.php(3): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /$$$$$/src/Google/autoload.php on line 14
[26-Jul-2019 20:05:19] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This library must be installed via composer or by downloading the full package. See the instructions at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation.' in /$$$$$/src/Google/autoload.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /$$$$$/googleauth.php(3): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /$$$$$/src/Google/autoload.php on line 14
[26-Jul-2019 20:18:25] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This library must be installed via composer or by downloading the full package. See the instructions at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation.' in /$$$$$/vendor/Google/autoload.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /$$$$$/googleauth.php(3): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /$$$$$/vendor/Google/autoload.php on line 14
[26-Jul-2019 20:19:09] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This library must be installed via composer or by downloading the full package. See the instructions at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation.' in /$$$$$/vendor/Google/autoload.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /$$$$$/googleauth.php(3): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /$$$$$/vendor/Google/autoload.php on line 14
[26-Jul-2019 20:25:41] PHP Warning:  require_once(__DIR__/composer/autoload_real.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /$$$$$/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
[26-Jul-2019 20:25:41] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear') in /$$$$$/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
[26-Jul-2019 20:28:17] PHP Warning:  require_once(__DIR__/composer/autoload_real.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /$$$$$/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
[26-Jul-2019 20:28:17] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear') in /$$$$$/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
[26-Jul-2019 22:09:46] PHP Warning:  require_once(__DIR__/composer/autoload_real.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /$$$$$/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
[26-Jul-2019 22:09:46] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear') in /$$$$$/vendor/autoload.php on line 5

/$$$$$/vendor/Google/error_log:
[26-Jul-2019 20:22:48] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /$$$$/vendor/Google/Client.php on line 18
```

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate https from an http site?

Comment: I am and that may be the issue. I figured that it would work unsecurely for now and I could figure out how to deal with https later

Comment: if that was what the problem was, that wouldn't explain why in the error log the require_once function is failing to load autoload_real.php, right?

Comment: set up https on cloudflare. it is free

Comment: If you're on shared hosting, relative paths might not work, as it may need your full path.

Comment: require_once 'vendor/autoload.php' successfully reaches the correct file because I can retrieve some dummy content (if I comment out everything else in that file). But there are literally hundreds of files in the google api so I'd be surprised if they expected people to change them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-read the API notes and it turns out that the PHP version does matter...

"REQUIREMENTS: PHP 5.4.0 or higher"

I've updated the version used on the server and am no longer receiving any errors